# Replace Windows filepath in text file by using a Linux sed regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, windows, parsing, sed

I have a huge number of text files with tag-like syntax. Those files contain patterns like this:

```
<TAG1=foo><TAG-2=\\10.0.0.1\directory\filename.pdf><TAG3> ...
<TAG4=bar><TAG-6=\\10.0.0.1\directory\filename.tif,other content><TAG5>
```

I need to replace the first part of those UNC paths with new ones, meaning:

```
<TAG1=foo><TAG-2=D:\localdirectory\filename.pdf><TAG3> ...
<TAG4=bar><TAG-6=D:\localdirectory\filename.tif,other content><TAG7>
```

There is a huge number of files to process and so I need to automate this path replacement. So far I tried multiple regex with sed (on Linux) but did not get close to a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

# New directory (escaped)
newpath='D:\\localdirectory\\'
# Actual replacement (don't work)
sed -i "s@\(<TAG-2=\)\([^\\]+\.pdf\)@\1${newpath}\2@g" filetoprocess.txt 
sed -i "s@\(<TAG-6=\)\([^\\]+\.tif\)@\1${newpath}\2@g" filetoprocess.txt
```

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came with the following regular expression. This solution can also, manage "/" Unix paths, dollar ($) and hyphens (-) :

```
sed -i -r 's@(<TAG-2=|TAG-6=)([\/]{2})([0-9.a-zA-Z_$ -]+[\/])+([0-9.a-zA-Z_$ -]+\.[pPtT][dDiI][fF])@\1'"${newpath}"'\\\4@g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This shell script using sed might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldpath='\\\\10\.0\.0\.1\\directory\\'
newpath='D:\\localdirectory\\'

#sed -i "s@${oldpath}@${newpath}@g" filetoprocess.txt
sed  -r -i "s@(<TAG-2=)${oldpath}([^>]+pdf)@\1${newpath}\2@g;
         s@(<TAG-6=)${oldpath}([^>]+tif)@\1${newpath}\2@g;
       " filetoprocess.txt
```

In the first line the shell shebang is `#!` (notice the exclamation mark). And I believe that the second line in your input example should have the TAG-6.

In the paths some care is necessary for the characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions:

- you have to escape the `.` und `\` with a backslash
- this leads to the funny looking `\\\\` (two escaped backslashes)

In the last line the `-r` option saves a bit of escaping in the argument. Note that I used `[^>]+` instead of `[^\\]+` to get the path part until the extension.

- The `[^\\]+` in your sed command would match everything after the `=` which is not a `\` and that is only the `D:` part.
- So your replacement would only match a literal `D:.pdf`.

But I would suggest trying the other (commented) sed command that just replaces the paths no matter what TAG and fileextension is.

(Backup your files before, since you use `-i` inplace replacement.)

Comment: @"Lars Fischer", thanks for this detailled answer. Of course 'olddpath' is not consistent over tens thousands of files I need to modify. Consitent elements are TAG syntax &filepath pattern: '\\fqdn or IP\subdir\subdir\filename.ext'... Also note the additionnal content in tag after the 'filename.tif', and closing '>'.

Comment: @donmelchior Consider `oldpath` and `newpath` are prefixes. The `([^>]+pdf)` should match the following path parts after the prefix up to and including the filename and the extension (`.pdf` in this case).